# Gluing topological spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory

The following is called a *gluing datum*:

- A family of topological spaces $(U_i)$,
- For all $i,j$ an open subset $U_{ij}\subseteq U_i$
- For all $i,j$ a map $\varphi_{ji}:U_{ij}\to U_{ji}$

such that

- $\varphi_{ii}=\operatorname{id}$ for aall $i$,
- $\varphi_{ji}(U_{ij}\cap U_{ik})\subseteq U_{ji}\cap U_{jk}$ for all $i,j,k$,
- $\varphi_{kj}\circ \varphi_{ji}=\varphi_{ki}$ on $U_{ij}\cap U_{ik}$ for all $i,j,k$.

Then there is a space $X$ together with open continous functions $\psi_i:U_i\to X$, such that

1) $X$ is covered by the images of the $U_i$,

2) $\psi_j\circ\varphi_{ji}=\psi_i$ on $U_{ij}$  for all $i,j$,

3) $\psi_i(U_i)\cap\psi_j(U_j)=\psi_i(U_{ij})=\psi_j(U_{ij})$ for all $i,j$.

Moreover, $X$ is universal with respect to 2).

> **Question:** What is happening here, categorically? Is this a special colimit? Does this have a name in category theory? Which parts are categorical nonsense and which are topology?

Thank you.

Comment: I cannot address the category theory, but I can tell you what the topology is. Generally speaking, when you have a bare, unadorned set $X$, a collection of topological spaces $U_i$, and a collection of functions $f_i : U_i \to X$, then there is an induced topology on $X$ which is the intersection of all topologies $\mathcal{T}$ such that each of the functions $f_i$ is continuous with respect to $\mathcal{T}$. One says this is the "weakest" or "coursest" topology with respect to which each $f_i$ is continuous.

Comment: Hint: To show that it is a colimit, you have to prove that $1)$ and $3)$ follow from the assumptions and $2)$, but for this, you have to make sure to take the right 'meaning' of *universal with respect to $2)$*.

Comment: A related, dual, (but not quite the same) categorial notion: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1619737/12885

Comment: @LeeMosher But here, a priori there is no set $X$ and no functions $f_i\to U$, which are used to equip $X$ with a topology, right? $X$ and $\psi_i$ are constructed from the gluing data.

Comment: @Ben So you are saying, that this is a colimit? I cannot see of which diagram it is a colimit. And the notion from EGA is really not the same, right? There are no maps $\varphi_{ji}$ there.

Comment: Good point. Again, I don't know the category theory words, but there is a straightforward description of the set $X$: it is the quotient set of the disjoint union of the sets $U_i$, using the equivalence relation that is generated by the relation where $x \in U_i$ is related to $y \in U_j$ if there exists $j$ such that $x \in U_{ij}$, $y \in U_{ji}$, and $\phi_{ji}(x)=y$.

Comment: Dear @user114885, yes, there are no $\varphi_{ij}$ there, but $U_{ij} = U_{ji}$, so you could say $\varphi_{ij} = \mathrm{id}$. Yours could be fit into this one by identifying $U_{ij}$ and $U_{ji}$ via the homeomorphism $\varphi_{ij}$. (Note that $\varphi_{ij}\circ\varphi_{ji} = \varphi_{ii} = \mathrm{id}$.) But I'll write an answer to provide a diagram without this detour soon.

Comment: I think you can translate the whole thing into abstract nonsense -- the key new idea is the *open subspace classifier*. If $S = \{0, 1\}$ is the Sierpinski space with topology $\{ \varnothing, \{1\}, S\}$, then there is a natural bijection between open subspaces of $X$ and continuous maps $X \to S$ that sends an open subspace to its indicator function.

Comment: @Ben: I don't see why $\varphi_{ij}$ and $\varphi_{ji}$ should be inverses; the hypotheses only immediately imply isomorphisms  $U_{ij} \cap U_{ii} \to U_{ji} \cap U_{jj}$.

Comment: Something is wrong/missing in the OP. We can form a counterexample by letting $U_1$ be any topological space and $U_{11}$ being any proper open subspace. Being universal with respect to (2) implies that $\psi_1 : U_1 \to X$ is a homeomorphism, but this contradicts (3) which insists that $\psi_1(U_1) = \psi_1(U_{11})$.

Comment: I suspect the omission is that $U_{ii} = U_i$.

Comment: Dear @Hurkyl, I was sure I read $U_{i}=U_{ii}$ somewhere, but you're right, it's not there even though it's necessary. What I was trying to say when I said there is a problem with subspaces was that the sub-object classifier doesn't really make it easier when you want to go further and say: now I want an abstract diagram category such that a functor to top is exactly a glueing datum and whose colimit is the glueing space.

Comment: Despite my thesis that the whole thing can be turned into abstract nonsense in a suitable category, it may be better to think of it as a combination of "you can carry out this topological idea in many categories" and "look at the parallels between algebra and geometry" rather than "it's just abstract nonsense".

Comment: @ben + hurkyl, thank you, your answers both helped me a lot to gain some intuition!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will assume that gluing data is also meant to include the condition $U_{ii} = U_i$.

I'm too tired to organize this all in a narrative, so this will be fairly disjointed.

---

It is fairly common in category theory to consider two families of objects $X_k$ and $X_{ij}$, families of maps $f_{ij} : X_{ij} \to X_i$ and $g_{ij} : X_{ij} \to X_j$, and the corresponding coequalizer

$$ \coprod_{ij} X_{ij} \overset{f}{\underset{g}{\rightrightarrows}} \coprod_k X_k \xrightarrow{\rho} X$$

or, if we include 'redundant' $X_{ii} = X_i$, a pushout square

$$ \begin{matrix} \coprod_{ij} X_{ij} &\xrightarrow{f}& \coprod_k X_k
\\ \!g\!\downarrow & & \downarrow\!\rho\!
\\ \coprod_k X_k &\xrightarrow{\rho}& X \end{matrix} $$

The picture here is that the $X_k$'s are a description of an object of interest, and the $X_{ij}$'s describe relations between the descriptions.

Geometrically, we might think of the $X_k$'s as a cover, and the $X_{ij}$'s describe the overlap between them. Algebraically, we might think of $X_k$ as being generators, and the $X_{ij}$ as being relations.

Either way, it's clear that in the "nicest" arrangement, we want each $X_{ij}$ to to be the pullback of $X_i \to X \leftarrow X_{j}$, so that it truly does describe *all* relations between $X_i$ and $X_j$, and you only really want one $X_{ij}$ per pair of indices.

Gluing data is in this nice situation, but not all such diagrams are: e.g. we might only have a more minimal description of the relations, or the covers might actually self-intersect nontrivially (e.g. taking the interval $X_1 = [0,2\pi]$ as a cover of the circle, with $X_{11}$ being a single point mapped to both ends) or other deficiencies may apply.

---

The gluing data gives an example of this sort of diagram: on each $U_{ij}$, the two maps into $\coprod_k U_k$ come from

- $ U_{ij} \hookrightarrow U_i $
- $ U_{ij} \xrightarrow{\varphi_{ji}} U_{ji} \hookrightarrow U_j $

Furthermore, the data does assert there is "just one" in the sense that the $\varphi_{ji}$ gives a homeomorphism $U_{ij} \to U_{ji}$, and they do so coherently in the sense that $\varphi_{ij} = \varphi_{ji}^{-1}$ and $\varphi_{ii} = 1_{U_i}$, so different "paths" $U_{ij} \to U_{ji}$ (e.g $\varphi_{ji}$ versus $\varphi_{ji} \circ \varphi_{ii} \circ \varphi_{ij} \circ \varphi_{ji}$) all give the same map.

---

The property that **Top** has that makes this setup convenient to work with is that it is [infinitary extensive](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extensive+category) — i.e. that coproducts really do act like disjoint unions. I do not know if this is actually *required*, but all the ways I want to reason about gluing data rely on it.

---

Sometimes, we also want to consider another family of $X_{ijk}$, this time with three maps down to the various $X_{mn}$.  We have this in gluing data too: we can define $U_{ijk} = U_{ij} \cap U_{ik}$. And again we have "just one" per triple of indices, because we again have coherent homeomorphisms between the different permutations. It is enough to check

- $U_{ijk} = U_{ikj}$
- $\varphi_{ji} : U_{ijk} \to U_{jik}$ is a homeomorphism
- The two homeomorphism $U_{ijk} \to U_{kji}$ given by $\varphi_{ki}$ and $\varphi_{kj} \circ \varphi_{ji}$ are the same.

We could go further. This leads to a simple example of a simplicial object.

---

**Top** is nice enough to talk about relations. The colimit defining $X$ can be viewed as taking the quotient of $\coprod_k U_k$ by the relation that the two maps $\coprod_{ij} U_{ij} \rightrightarrows \coprod_k U_k$ give equivalent outputs for each input.

Normally, this relation is not an equivalence relation, and so the quotient is by the equivalence relation *generated* by this relation.

However, the neat thing about having the transition maps $\varphi$ is that the relation really is an equivalence relation, so the colimit is much, much easier to work with. The interesting part is that it is a transitive relation, which you can check by noting that

$$ x \sim \varphi_{ji}(x) \quad \text{and} \quad \varphi_{ji}(x) \sim \varphi_{kj}(\varphi_{ji}(x)) $$

only makes sense when $x \in U_{ijk}$, and that the transitive property requires $x \sim \varphi_{ki}(x)$, which we have.

---

In **Top**, having the transition maps implies that the $\psi_i : U_i \to X$ are monic. I think you can even argue it's regular monic. Off hand I don't know what you want from the category to say such things.

---

Finally, last feature is about *open subspaces*. While seemingly the part most topological in flavor, it too has an abstract analog.

**Top** has a *open subspace classifier*. Let $S = \{0,1\}$ be the Sierpinski space, with topology $\{\varnothing, \{1\}, S\}$. Then there is a natural bijection between open subspaces of $X$ and continuous maps $X \to S$:

- For every open subset $U \subseteq X$, the characteristic function $\chi_U : X \to S$ is continuous
- For any continuous map $\chi : X \to S$, the inverse image $f^{-1}(1)$ is an open subset

You can thus show that $\psi_i(U_i) \subseteq X$ is an open subspace by showing that the maps
$$ \chi_{ij} : \coprod_i U_j \to S : x \mapsto \begin{cases}
1 & x \in U_{ji} \\ 0 & x \notin U_{ji} \end{cases} $$
induce a well-defined map $\chi_i : X \to S$, and that $\chi_i^{-1}(1) = \psi_i(U_i)$.

Off hand, I'm not sure what additional properties you need (if any) to be able to make this argument in **Top**.

Answer (score 4):

Here comes a diagram in $\mathrm(Top)$ whose colimit is the desired glueing. Given a glueing datum as in the question text, the diagram will consist of

- all $U_i$ and all $U_{ij}$ as objects
  and
- the inclusion maps $U_{ij}\to U_i$ as well as all $\varphi_{ij}$ as morphisms.

This feels a bit ad-hoc, I have to admit, but it works. If we were to write down a more general/abstract diagram, it were harder to translate that the $U_{ij}$ are actually subspaces of the $U_i$ and not just merely spaces mapping to $U_i$, but besides that, it's not too hard. But under weaker assumptions, I think $3)$ might not hold for the colimit.

Let me recall (from Lee Mosher's comment) that the following space, with the obvious maps, is a colimit for the above diagram:
$$X := \coprod\nolimits_i U_i\,/{\sim},\text{ where }\sim\text{ identifies }U_{ij}\text{ with }U_{ji}\text{ via }\varphi_{ij} = \varphi_{ji}^{-1}.$$
This space is easily seen to fulfil the properties $1), 2), 3)$, so actually, there is nothing more to prove, by uniqueness. Nevertheless, we should look at what's going on in case there are only two spaces $U_1,U_2$ with subspaces $U_{12}\subset U_1$, $U_{21}\subset U_2$, with continuous maps $\varphi_{12}\colon U_{21}\to U_{12}$ and $\varphi_{21}\colon U_{12}\to U_{21}$, being mutually inverse. Then the diagram is just
$$
\newcommand{\ra}[2]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mathop{\rightleftarrows}\limits^{#1}_{#2}\quad\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\int}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{rcl}
U_{12} & \ra{\varphi_{21}}{\varphi_{12}} & U_{21} \\
\da{} & & \da{}  \\
U_{1} &  & U_2 \\
\end{array}
$$
A colimit of this diagram boils down to a space $X$ with maps $\psi_i\colon U_i\to X$ such that the following diagram commutes, and the universal property that the continuous maps $f\colon X\to Y$ are, via pull-back to $U_1$ and $U_2$, in bijection with pairs $f_i = f\circ\psi_i\colon U_i\to Y$ such that $(f_1)|_{U_{12}} = f_2\circ\varphi_{21}$ (and then automatically also $(f_2)|_{U_{21}} = f_1\circ\varphi_{12}$).

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[2]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\mathop{\rightleftarrows}\limits^{#1}_{#2}\quad\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\int}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{rcl}
U_{12} & \ra{\varphi_{21}}{\varphi_{12}} & U_{21} \\
\da{} && \da{}  \\
U_{1} & & U_2 \\
&\searrow^{\psi_1}\;\;\;\;\swarrow_{\psi_2}&\\
& X & \\
\end{array}
$$

We must show that this implies $1)$ and $3)$ as in the question.
This is where we see what's formal and what's rather special to $(Top)$.
The universal property implies that $\coprod_i U_i\xrightarrow{\psi} X$ is an epimorphism and this is enough for the map so be surjective (in $\mathrm{(Top)}$!); therefore, $X$ is covered by $U_1$ and $U_2$ and $1)$ holds.
$3)$, however, is more involved. It relies on the fact that (in $\mathrm{(Top)}$!) some push-out squares are also pull-back squares. I'm running out of time for more details right now, so let's just say *that $3)$ holds relies very much on the fact that we're talking about $\mathrm{(Top)}$ and on the assumption that the $U_{ij}\subset U_i$ be subspaces*. (I think I will only provide more details upon request.)